# Difference between parse() of DateFormat and SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, java-8

I am trying to parse the date using `LocalDateTime.parse` the method however I am getting below error. the date string is getting parse if I use `SimpleDateFormat` simple date format object.

Has anyone faced this issue! What's the difference between parse from `DateFormat` and `LocalDateTime`

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Date;

public class App {

    public static final String DATE_TIME_PATTERN = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS";

    public static final DateFormat DATE_TIME_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_TIME_PATTERN);

    public static final String SEPERATOR = ",";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Date date = DATE_TIME_FORMAT.parse("12-03-2019 10:28:50.013");
            System.out.println("date : {} " + date);

            LocalDateTime startTimestamp = LocalDateTime.parse("12-03-2019 10:28:50.013", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_TIME_PATTERN)).plusNanos(1000000);
            System.out.println("startTimestamp : {} " + startTimestamp);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
date : {} Tue Mar 12 10:28:50 SGT 2019
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '12-03-2019 10:28:50.013' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {NanoOfSecond=13000000, HourOfAmPm=10, MicroOfSecond=13000, SecondOfMinute=50, MilliOfSecond=13, MinuteOfHour=28},ISO resolved to 2019-03-12 of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.createError(DateTimeFormatter.java:1920)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1855)
    at java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492)
    at com.example.demo.App.main(App.java:21)
Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {NanoOfSecond=13000000, HourOfAmPm=10, MicroOfSecond=13000, SecondOfMinute=50, MilliOfSecond=13, MinuteOfHour=28},ISO resolved to 2019-03-12 of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.time.LocalDateTime.from(LocalDateTime.java:461)
    at java.time.format.Parsed.query(Parsed.java:226)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain LocalTime from TemporalAccessor: {NanoOfSecond=13000000, HourOfAmPm=10, MicroOfSecond=13000, SecondOfMinute=50, MilliOfSecond=13, MinuteOfHour=28},ISO resolved to 2019-03-12 of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.time.LocalTime.from(LocalTime.java:409)
    at java.time.LocalDateTime.from(LocalDateTime.java:457)
    ... 4 more
```

Comment: IMO, it is just like `SimpleDateFormat`is from older version while `DateFormat ` is from java-8 onward, more powerful and thread safe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the **clock-hour-of-am-pm (1-12)** for hour which is **`h`** in your pattern and not **hour-of-day (0-23)** which is **`H`**, so it needs the additional info of the AM/PM.

[image]

So ideally the AM/PM must be mentioned in the date string which is to be parsed along with **`a`** for **am-pm-of-day** which also needs to be added in the `DATE_TIME_PATTERN` String.

```
public static final String DATE_TIME_PATTERN = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS a";

public static final DateFormat DATE_TIME_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_TIME_PATTERN);

  public static final String SEPERATOR = ",";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Date date = DATE_TIME_FORMAT.parse("12-03-2019 10:28:50.013 AM");
            System.out.println("date : {} " + date);

            LocalDateTime startTimestamp = LocalDateTime.parse("12-03-2019 10:28:50.013 AM", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_TIME_PATTERN)).plusNanos(1000000);
            System.out.println("startTimestamp : {} " + startTimestamp);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Output:

```
date : {} Tue Mar 12 10:28:50 IST 2019
startTimestamp : {} 2019-03-12T10:28:50.014
```

We can see that without the proper format `SimpleDateFormat` is working while `LocalDateTime` is more stricter when it comes to parsing invalid date strings. In your case since the required AM/PM info is missing, the `LocalTime` returned from the `TemporalAccessor` is `null` and hence you are getting `Unable to obtain LocalTime from TemporalAccessor`.

No coming to why `SimpleDateFormat` is working, there is a method called [`setLenient(boolean lenient)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient(boolean)) if you pass hour which is greater than `12` without mentioning `a` in the pattern and AM/PM in the date string  an `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date:` will be thrown.

But since in your case you are passing the hour as `10` this is less than `12` and hence it is interpreted as **AM** by default.

This is the code in SimpleDateFormat class where this checking is happening:

```
case PATTERN_HOUR1: // 'h' 1-based.  eg, 11PM + 1 hour =>> 12 AM
     if (!isLenient()) {
         // Validate the hour value in non-lenient
         if (value < 1 || value > 12) {
             break parsing;
         }
     }
     // [We computed 'value' above.]
     if (value == calendar.getLeastMaximum(Calendar.HOUR) + 1) {
         value = 0;
     }
     calb.set(Calendar.HOUR, value);
     return pos.index;
```